# Estimating and fitting a GARCH model

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, arima, garch

By far I've become really familiar with the concept of GARCH but I'm still confused on how to go on with the implementation especially that I've seen multiple sources using different approaches:

1. Should I: a. Find an arima model using **auto.arima** , b. check the residuals for heteroscedasticity,
   c. fit a GARCH model to residuals ??

(and here I have no idea how to select the order of GARCH except for manually going over different models one by one)

*Or*

2. Should I: a. Test for ARCH effect in raw data itself
   b. Use **rugarch** to fit the mean and variance equations simultaneously.

And here do I do the fitting for the raw data itself or is it possible to use the residuals of the mean equation in case I have previously estimated it?

(Again regardless of data used, I'm unable to find a way to select the order of the variance equation without having to go over multiple models one by one)

---

Finally what's the difference between the two approaches and which one yield more accurate and efficient parameters?

P.S. running **auto.arima** on my data gave me a (2,0,2) arima model. Basically I'm unsure how to proceed next.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.